# How to send email from Laravel to Real email address

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel app with a contact form. In local I was using mailtrap.io to test for emails being sent from the contact form and the emails were going through. I deployed my app and now when I submit a contact form, the user information gets stored in my database but the page re-directs and throws a 500 error. How do I send emails in a production enviornment? In local dev the page redirected back to my home and gave a flash message perfectly.

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=mailtrap-username
MAIL_PASSWORD=mailtrap-pw
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Name Here"
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/ultimate-guide-on-sending-email-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps to send Email.

.Env

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USERNAME = your-gmail-username
MAIL_PASSWORD = your-application-specific-password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls
```

Send through `Mail` class with `raw` function.

```
\Mail::raw('Hi, welcome user!', function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', 'text/html');
});
```

Second way is `send` function:-

```
\Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to('my@email.com')
    ->subject('my subject')
    ->setBody('Hi, welcome user!'); 
});
```

Hope It will work for you. Thanks!